# Is it (efficiently) possible to get a list of elements in JavaScript that have a certain CSS property set?

Tags: javascript, css

I know we can use `document.querySelectorAll(yada yada yada)` to get a list of elements that match any CSS *selector*, but is it possible to come at the problem from another angle, and match any element with a certain CSS *property*?

I've written a function to shrink any flex-wrap containers to the correct size, without the ugly gap on the right hand side that current CSS means we're always stuck with.  (Aside: is there something in an upcoming spec to fix this issue?)

I'd like it to run automatically on any flex-wrap containers on my site.

I don't want to add a `class="flex-wrap"` to each element.  I know tailwind et al are all about this type of classes these days, but I'm old school.  I believe in separation of design/content and that class/IDs should be semantic, not stylistic.

But for this "problem", the only solutions I can see are:

1. manually add IDs/classes of elements which I know need the fix in my JavaScript
2. add a class that `querySelectorAll` can latch on to
3. loop through every element calling `getComputedStyles()` to check for this CSS property.  I've not tried that, as some of my pages have many thousands of DOM elements, and I know it's a terrible idea.

Is there a better 4th option that I've not considered?

Comment: You might loop over all the style sheets and rules to find those that have the property you want, then see which elements the rules apply to. No idea if that's practical or sensible (it will not check in–line style rules or default properties), but it is another approach. :-)

Comment: I prefer 2nd. Don't have 4th option

Comment: 3. would give you absolute certainty (though you'd have to do it on any change which would be awful) so 2. looks like the practical option even though I understand you don't like using class this way, though aren't you trying to classify those elements? You could use data- instead.

Comment: I'm going with 1 at the moment, especially since I've realised that to avoid an ugly jump I normally need to have `visibility: hidden` set on an ancestor some way up the chain, until the function has run. (For this I use a `"jsblank"` class which gets `document.write`d in my `<head>` so that it falls back gracefully without JavaScript.